# Changing a displayed image inside mainloop on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, display

I'm trying to make a program to display a single color, fullscreen. The idea is to use it on a large screen to create environment in the room, the screen changing from color to color after certain time.

Displaying the color fullscreen is not a problem but how can I change said color smoothly?

For the fullscreen display I've used a Tkinter window with the same size as the screen: `imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2, h/2, image=image)` where `image` is a certain color. But to change the color I need to destroy the window using `root.after(2000, root.destroy)` and then create a new one. This is not smooth as the desktop can be seen for a brief moment.

How can I change the image displayed inside a Tkinter window on the go, or, how can I close one window and open another one smoothly?

Comment: Just use `canvas.itemconfig(imagesprite, image=image)` to change image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option you have is instead of using an image is to have a background for the Canvas object. Here is the minimum code to have a single colour background.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)#Makes the window fullscreen
canvas = Canvas(root, width=root.winfo_width(),height=root.winfo_height(), background="red") #Makes a canvas with a red coloured background
#The width and height of the Canvas are taken from the root object
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

From here, instead of deleting the window constantly, it is possible to just change the attributes of Tkinter widgets. This is done using the config method.

```
canvas.config(background="green")
```

A great thing about tkinter is that you can give it a hex code for the colour and it will draw use that. It needs to be in a string formatted like this:
`"#RRGGBB"` where each group is a hexadecimal number from 0 to FF.

With this in mind, you can increase the hexadecimal number each frame or however many frames you want between two colours. To have a good transition, you may want to use Hue,Saturation,Value (HSV) colours, and only change the Hue value.

You can store the HSV in a list:

```
hsv = [0,0.7,0.7]
```

To convert, you first want to convert to 0 to 255 RGB and then to Hexadecimal.

```
import colorsys
rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*hsv) #Uses list unpacking to give it as arguments
```

Next, you use the rgb and turn it into Hexcode form.

```
def getHexCode(rgb):
    r = hex(int(rgb[0]*255))[2:] #converts to hexadecimal
    #With the hex() function, it returns a number in "0xFE" format (0x representing hex).
    #To ignore this, we can take the substring using [2:]
    if len(r) < 2: #If the value is a 1-digit number, then we want to add a zero at the front for hexcode form
        r = "0"+r
    g = hex(int(rgb[1]*255))[2:]
    if len(g) < 2:
        g = "0"+g
    b = hex(int(rgb[2]*255))[2:]
    if len(b) < 2:
        b = "0"+b

    return "#" + r + g + b
```

Finally, we actually call the change method.

```
changeSpeed = 200
def changeColor():
    rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*hsv)
    hexCode = getHexCode(rgb)
    canvas.config(background = hexCode)
    hsv[0]+=0.01
    root.after(changeSpeed,changeColor)

root.after(changeSpeed, changeColor)
```

(EDITED)
Two things that were previously a problem were the `root.winfo_width()` and `root.winfo_height()`, as well as the fullscreen giving a border.

To solve the first problem, we have to somehow update the root object, since by default it's 1x1. What we can do for that is make the `Canvas` object and then update it. It looks like this:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=100,height=100, background="white",highlightthickness=0) #Makes a canvas with a white coloured background
canvas.pack()
canvas.update()
canvas.config(width = root.winfo_width(), height = root.winfo_height())
```

The second problem is also solved by making the canvas object with a specific attribute, `highlightthickness=0`. If you notice, the canvas object initialization is now:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=100,height=100, background="white",highlightthickness=0)
```

Another thing that I thought was useful is if a button closes the program. I bound the "Escape" key to the closing using the following:

```
def quit(event):
    root.destroy()

root.bind("<Escape>", quit)
```

As a full program, it looks like this:

```
import colorsys
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas

hsv = [0,1,0.8]
changeSpeed = 200

root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
canvas = Canvas(root, width=100,height=100, background="white",highlightthickness=0) #Makes a canvas with a white coloured background
canvas.pack()
canvas.update()
canvas.config(width = root.winfo_width(), height = root.winfo_height())


def getHexCode(rgb):
    r = hex(int(rgb[0]*255))[2:]
    if len(r) < 2:
        r = "0"+r
    g = hex(int(rgb[1]*255))[2:]
    if len(g) < 2:
        g = "0"+g
    b = hex(int(rgb[2]*255))[2:]
    if len(b) < 2:
        b = "0"+b

    return "#" + r + g + b

def changeColor():
    rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*hsv)
    hexCode = getHexCode(rgb)
    canvas.config(background = hexCode)
    hsv[0]+=0.01
    root.after(changeSpeed,changeColor)

def quit(event):
    root.destroy()

root.after(changeSpeed, changeColor)
root.bind("<Escape>", quit)

root.mainloop()
```

Some variables you can change in this is the changeSpeed, the original hsv list, and the 0.01 that is added to the hue each increase

Comment: Thank you so much, looks like this is what I needed. Unfortunately, even when copying and pasting this code, the pgrogram does not work. It always opens a white fullscreen window. Even when I comment everything else but the red canvas declaration, the windows is white.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. The value of root.winfo_width() and root.winfo_height() was 1 (I don't know why), changing width and height for the appropiate values for my monitor solved it and now it works fine.

Comment: Lastly, the fullscreen window still has a white frame, regardless of the background color. Can this be fixed?

Comment: I'll look into it, I noticed it too

Comment: Fixed, check the edits, also added in so that if you hit escape, it will close the program